# How to implement a efficient structure like GRU in pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I have a model A which is pretrained. This model A will take x_{t-1} and p_{t} to predict x_{t}. Since it is actually a PyTorch neural network it is differentiable.
What I want to do is I want this model to move along P ={p_i} (a sequence predicted from last layer) and predict X = {x_i}.
However, to predict x_{t} this model needs to take the output of the last frame x_{t-1}. Thus, I implemented this structure using a for loop which makes the process quite slow…

Is there a way to accelerate the process?
This structure is quite similar to GRU or LSTM, but GRU is much faster, how can I improve it?

Comment: If the process is sequential in time, wouldn't it be necessary to have a for loop in the implementation?

Comment: @Ivan Yes. But it is much more slower than GRU or LSTM...